# Удалить повторяющиеся элементы в двумерном массиве чисел

Tags: javascript

Как в отсортированном двумерном массиве мне удалить все повторяющиеся элементы?

```
var mas = new Array(localStorage.length);
mas['A'] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('A'));
mas['A'].sort();
//так почему-то не работает
// for (var i = mas['A'].length; i > 0; i--)
// {
//     if (mas['A'][i] == mas['A'][i-1]) mas['A'][i].splice(i,1);
// }
//пример данных mas['A']
//0: Array [ 1, 10 ]
//1: Array [ 1, 10 ]
//2: Array [ 3, 10 ]
```

​​

Comment: Представьте - к Вам на улице подходит старушка и говорит: "Милок, почему у меня не сортируется массив?" Что Вы ей ответите? Вариант: "Бабка, ты бы хоть сказала, что у тебя там за данные в массиве!"

Comment: @Igor а есть способ тогда без сортировки?

Comment: Товарищ не понимает. Уберите из кода `new Array` и `localStorage`. Добавьте пример данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Способ через `map`, `stringify` и `JSON.parse`

```js
var entryArray = [
  [10, 20],
  [10, 20],
  [20, 10],
  [20, 10],
];

let set = new Set(entryArray.map(JSON.stringify));
let uniqArray = Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse);

console.log(uniqArray)
```

Так же хорошо сработает, если во вложенных массивах больше чем 2 значения или объекты.

```js
var entryArray = [
  [10, 20, 10],
  [10, 20, 10],
  [20, 10, 20],
  [20, 10, 20],
  [30, 10, 20],
  [30, 10, 20],
  [30, 10, 20, 400],
  [30, 10, 20, 400],
  [{
    a: "value1"
  }],
  [{
    a: "value1"
  }],
  [{
    b: "value2"
  }],
];

let set = new Set(entryArray.map(JSON.stringify));
let uniqArray = Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse);

console.log(uniqArray)
```

Comment: -1 - `let testArray = [[10, 20],[10, 21],[20, 10],[20, 11]];`

Comment: @Igor точно, спасибо. ваш способ нельзя назвать универсальным, если во вложенном массиве будет больше чем 2 значения, то уже не сработает.

Comment: кхм, кхм... При чем здесь два значения? Что не сработает? Я Вам привел пример данных, с которыми Ваш код не справится. У Вас есть пример для меня?

Comment: @Igor исправил. +1

Comment: @NikitaSmith спасибо. Только я не совсем понял как вызвать правильно. Если я  записываю из localStorage в mas['A']. Поясните, пожалуйста немного подробнее

Comment: @ВладиславВернер считай что твой массив с вложенными массивами есть entryArray, потом на выходе ты получаешь uniqArray, в котором нету дубликатов.

Comment: @NikitaSmith благодарен. Действительно работает.

Comment: @ВладиславВернер пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Подумайте, чей метод `splice` вызывается вот здесь:

```
mas['A'][i].splice(i,1);
```

---

P.S. Уберите из кода `new Array` и `localStorage`. Добавьте пример данных.

---

P.P.S. Я знаю, в чем дело, но не скажу до тех пор, пока Вы не добавите в вопрос пример данных.

---

*Update*

Когда Вы сравниваете `mas['A'][i] == mas['A'][i-1]`, сравниваются две ссылки на разные экземпляры массивов. Они никогда не будут равны.

```js
var data = [
  [ 3, 10 ],
  [ 1, 10 ],
  [ 1, 10 ],
  [ 3, 10 ]
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var sa = JSON.stringify(a);
  var sb = JSON.stringify(b);
  return (sa < sb)? -1 : ((sa > sb)? 1 : 0);
});
for (var i = data.length; i > 0; i--)
{
  var sa = JSON.stringify(data[i]);
  var sb = JSON.stringify(data[i - 1]);
  if (sa == sb) 
    data.splice(i,1);
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Поправил на mas['A'].splice(i,1); и всё равно не удаляет. Не понимаю. Данные в массиве - каждый элемент массива ['A'] - две цифры от 0 до 10

Comment: @ВладиславВернер Вы хотите, чтобы мы продолжали гадать? Данных - тех, что в массиве - я так понимаю, Вы не покажете?

Comment: @ВладиславВернер "каждый элемент ... - две цифры от 0 до 10" -  что это, черт возьми, может значить?

Comment: mas['A'] массив координат. mas['A'][0] = [0,0]. Каждый элемент mas['A'][i] = массив из двух чисел от 0 до 10. Массив сортируется. Первый элемент, например, 1 1, второй элемент 1 1 (если отсортирован)

Comment: @ВладиславВернер Я знаю,  в чем дело, но не скажу до тех пор, пока Вы не добавите в вопрос пример данных.

Comment: изменил в вопросе