# javascript: set для массивов

Tags: javascript, производительность, set

подскажите, можно ли использовать `Set` для того, чтобы оставить только уникальные массивы

т.е. чтобы из `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`
осталось только `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4]]`

или для такой задачи есть другие средства?

не хотелось бы делать через поиск в массиве по каждому элементу

Comment: set же в javascript по определению не допускает дублирования. Так что должно быть можно, как и в Python. Но не знаю javascript. А почему просто не проверить? Вот, кстати, и ссылка, что можно: <https://myrusakov.ru/js-removing-duplicates-array.html>

Comment: @Сергей, в том то и дело, что проверил и Set удаляет дубликаты у чисел, но вообще никак не реагирует на массивы :(

Comment: так странно. В ссылке как раз про массивы говорится...

Comment: попробуйте вот это посмотреть. тут `set` используется, вроде. Но сложно понять до деталей, языка не зная:-) <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888613/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB>

Comment: "не хотелось бы делать через поиск в массиве по каждому элементу", не хочу вас разочаровывать, но по моему по другому никак.

Comment: @NNL, мощные языки должны иметь массу способов эффективной обработки стандартных ситуаций. Если мы видим, что обработка не очень эффективна, то это, скорее всего, означает, что мы не знаем чего-то.

Comment: @Сергей нет никаких идей как ещё это можно реализовать в данном случае с такими условиями, можете предложить какой-нибудь вариант? (Просто интересно как это можно сделать по другому)

Comment: @ΝNL993, см.ответ Stanislav Volodarskiy, например

Comment: @Сергей, но там ведь тоже проходятся по всем элементам массива, разве метод `map` это не делает?

Comment: @NNL, скорость встроенного метода должна быть выше. Иначе можно справедливо сказать, что и `set` проходится по всем элементам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Массивы сохраняем в строки, [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) умеет работать со строками правильно, фильтрованные строки переводим в массивы:

```js
arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
result = [
    ...new Set(arrays.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)))
].map(s => JSON.parse(s));
console.log(result);
```

`Set` хранит переданные ему объекты без дубликатов. К сожалению, в JavaScript одинаковые массивы не равны:

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]);
```

А значит для `Set` одинаковые массивы выглядят разными. Не спешите ругать язык - в Питоне массив в `set` вообще поместить нельзя. Поля этой книги маловаты чтобы объяснить почему. Правда в Питоне есть кортежи (которые в `set` отлично вставляются), а в JavaScript их нет (тут можно немного поругаться).

Раз нельзя с массивами, переведём их в строки. Со строками `Set` работает правильно: равные строки действительно равны с точки зрения языка.

У предложенного способа есть недостаток: фильтруются не сами массивы а их копии. Это не всегда удобно, но обойти можно с помощью [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Создаётся отображение `<строка>: <массив>`. Ключи не повторяются, в результат попадают оригинальные массивы. Ещё сэкономили на `JSON.parse`:

```js
arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
result = [...new Map(arrays.map(a => [JSON.stringify(a), a])).values()];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Вот, спасибо, я был уверен, что должен быть способ! Очень странно иметь совпадающие типы в разных языках, которые вдруг совсем уж по-разному работают.

Comment: А зачем вы переводите значения входного массива в строку? Можете в ответе объяснить? Немного непонятен этот момент.

Comment: а если [1,2,3] [3,2,1]?

Comment: @splash58, предварительная сортировка решает задачу.

Comment: я просто про сортировку не увидел

Comment: Её не было в ответе, потому что её не было в вопросе.

Comment: `.map(JSON.parse)` не делайте так) Не нужно лишние параметры передавать, это может однажды что-то сломать.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо! Теперь в обоих местах лишние аргументы обрезаны. Так годится?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, 

Comment: Можно было сделать Map.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у `Map` все те же проблемы, что и у `Set`: ключи надо будет сделать строками. Значения могут остаться оригинальными массивами. Такое решение выдаст оригинальные массивы в ответе (не копии). Избавимся от `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Нет. При вставке массива, в Set будет установлена ссылка и она же проверена на дубликат.

Придется написать что-то вроде этого:

```js
// Неупорядоченное сравнение элементов массива
function isEquals (a1, a2) {
  const length = a1.length
  if (length !== a2.length) return false
  const indexes = [...Array(length).fill(0).keys()]
  const includes = (e) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
      if (e === a2[indexes[i]]) {
        indexes.splice(i, 1)
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (!includes(a1[i])) return false
  }
  return true
}

function uniq (arrs) {
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arrs.length; ++i) {
    if (!result.some((e) => isEquals(arrs[i], e))) 
      // если копируем добавим .slice()
      result.push(arrs[i].slice())
  }
  return result
}

const arr = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
  // можно даже перемешать массив, он тоже будет пропущен
  [3, 2, 1]
]
console.log(uniq(arr))
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < arrs.length; ++i) {if (!result.some((e) => isEquals(arrs[i], e))) result.push(arrs[i].slice())` Это и есть «производительный способ, не основанный на поиске в массиве по каждому элементу»?

Comment: @wololo Я не понял вопроса. Может следует указать более конкретнее на участок кода или показать пример что не так?

Comment: Автор вопроса поставил метку производительность и написал, `не хотелось бы делать через поиск в массиве по каждому элементу`, что заставляет меня думать, что алгоритмы со сложностью `O(n**2)` его не устраивают. Ладно, может я не прав.

Answer (score 0):

Если на входе у Set-а первый аргумент массив, то он из него уже создаёт новый Set, а остальное не трогает.

Пример:

```js
console.log([...new Set([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7, 8, 9).keys()])
```

Если же вы добавляете массивы через метод `add`, то тогда Set "переобразует" массив в [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) (Кратко: уникальный объект), то есть для Set это будут два уникальных массива (Symbol), и поэтому он их трогать не будет.

Пример:

```js
let s = new Set
s.add([1, 2, 3])
s.add([1, 2, 3])
s.add([4, 5, 6])
let keys = [...s.keys()]
console.log(keys)
console.log(keys[0] === keys[1]) // [1, 2, 3] === [1, 2, 3] // не совсем корректное выражение, но суть вы поняли
```

А чтобы проверить массив, и убрать не уникальные массивы можно сделать простую проверку.

Код:

```js
let arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ]

arr.filter((e, i, a) => {
    return a.splice(i, 1).includes(e)
}) 

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: 1) `Если же вы добавляете массивы через метод add, то тогда Set "переобразует" массив в Symbol` Серьёзно? А чего тогда `Array.isArray(s.values().next().value)` возвращает `true`? 2) `А чтобы проверить массив, и убрать не уникальные массивы можно сделать простую проверку` Судя по выводу ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @wololo 1) Никогда не слышал о методе `next`, можете скинуть страницу документации (Сам не нашёл)? 2) Поправил.

Comment: [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)

Comment: Поправленный вариант массив `arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` превращает в `[[4,5,6]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность поставить массиву в соответствие уникальное значение, то можно использовать map:

```js
var data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

function toKey(a) {
  return a + ""
}

var res = [...new Map(data.map(x => [toKey(x), x])).values()]

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```